# JQuery - get id of div element with same class name

Tags: jquery, asp.net, get

I need to pick id od **selectable** when Test1 or Test2 are clicked.

```
    <div class="selectable" id="1">
         <span class="ui-state-default">Test1</span></asp:Label>
     </div>

    <div class="selectable" id="2">
         <span class="ui-state-default">Test2</span></asp:Label>
    </div>
```

I try somethnig, but i only get first time good value, i get always same value next times.

```
        $(".selectable").selectable({
            stop: function() {
            $(".ui-selected", this).each(function() {
                alert($(".ui-selected").closest("div").attr("id"));
                });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `$(this)` in your `.each()` function instead of `$(".ui-selected")`:

```
$(".selectable").selectable({
    stop: function() {
        $(".ui-selected", this).each(function() {
            alert($(this).closest("div").attr("id"));
        });
    }
});
```

Otherwise only the first `.ui-selected` (and consequently the first parent `div`) will be looked at, and you'll only get the first `div`'s ID.